# Jquery price filter slider issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have jquery price filter with filter button but now i want to filter data without button by using onchange function. I have implemented this jquery slider in codeigniter but it is not working with onchange function.

This is my view page:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <h4 class="pb-1"><span>Price Range</span></h4>
            <!--Range slider -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
           <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;"> Min </span>
            <input type="text" id="value-min" name="min_price" required="" /  style="width:56%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
           <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">Max </span> 
           <input type="text" id="value-max" name="max_price" required="" /  style="width:56%"> 
            </div>
    Here in this div i want add onchange function:

           <div id="pmd-slider-value-range"  class="pmd-range-slider" min="<?= $deals_min_max_prices->min_price ?>" max="<?= $deals_min_max_prices->max_price ?>" onChange="this.form.submit();"></div> <br/>

           <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:-18px !important;margin-bottom: 10px!important;">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Filter</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is jquery code for slider:

```
 var pmdSliderValueRange = document.getElementById('pmd-slider-value-range');

noUiSlider.create(pmdSliderValueRange, {

start: [<?= $deals_min_max_prices->current_min_price ?>, <?= $deals_min_max_prices->current_max_price ?>], // Handle start position

connect: true, // Display a colored bar between the handles

tooltips: [wNumb({decimals: 0}), wNumb({decimals: 0})],

format: wNumb({

    decimals: 0,

    thousand: '',

    postfix: '',

}),

range: {// Slider can select '0' to '100'

    'min': <?= $deals_min_max_prices->min_price ?>,

    'max': <?= $deals_min_max_prices->max_price ?>

},

step: 5,

pips: {

    mode: 'steps',

    density: 10

}

});

var valueMax = document.getElementById('value-max'),

    valueMin = document.getElementById('value-min');
```

When the slider value changes, update the input and span

```
pmdSliderValueRange.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {

if (handle) {

    valueMax.value = values[handle];

} else {

    valueMin.value = values[handle];

}

});
```

This is my controller:

```
$this->data['deals_min_max_prices'] = $this->deals_model->get_deals_min_max_prices($min_max_filters);
$this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->current_min_price = $this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->min_price;
$this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->current_max_price = $this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->max_price;
if ($this->input->get_post('min_price')) {
    $this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->current_min_price = $this->input->get_post('min_price');
}
if ($this->input->get_post('max_price')) {
    $this->data['deals_min_max_prices']->current_max_price = $this->input->get_post('max_price');
}
```

This is model:

```
 function get_deals_min_max_prices($filters = []) {
$this->db->select('min(deals.deal_price) as min_price,max(deals.deal_price) as max_price');
$this->db->from('deals');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id=deals.categories_id');
$this->db->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.id=deals.sub_categories_id');
$this->db->join('stores', 'stores.id=deals.stores_id');
$this->db->where("deals.status", 1);
foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
    if ($key == 'deals.tags') {
        $cond = array();
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $cond[] = 'FIND_IN_SET("' . $val . '",deals.tags) != 0';
        }
        $this->db->where('(' . implode(' OR ', $cond) . ')');
    } else {
        $key_array = explode(' ', $key);
        if (isset($key_array[1]) && ($key_array[1] == "!=")) {
        $this->db->where_not_in($key_array[0], $value);
        } else {
        $this->db->where_in($key, $value);
        }
    }
    } elseif ($key == 'deals.deal_title') {
    $this->db->like($key, $value);
    } elseif ($key == 'deals.tags') {
    $this->db->where('FIND_IN_SET("' . $value . '",deals.tags) !=', 0);
    } else {
    $this->db->where($key, $value);
    }
}
$data = $this->db->get()->row();
if ($data) {
    return $data;
}
return (object) array('min_price' => 0, 'max_price' => 100);
}
```

Comment: try  `pmdSliderValueRange.noUiSlider.on('change', function(values, handle)`

Comment: _Side note:_ When closing self closing html elements like `<input />`'s, the slash should go last: `/>`, not between attributes.

Comment: Thank you @Gulshan. Already tried but not working

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'll keep that in mind

Comment: where is your onChange event handler? onchange of what attribute the function should call?

Comment: @sony here :  <div id="pmd-slider-value-range"  class="pmd-range-slider" min="<?= $deals_min_max_prices->min_price ?>" max="<?= $deals_min_max_prices->max_price ?>" onChange="this.form.submit();"></div>

Comment: @Prajakta, please go through this url, it might help you. URL: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-html5. I hope you have add addEventListner() to your code

Comment: @sony No. i haven't added addEventListner()